# Extract YearWeek from a date

Tags: xquery

I am trying to achieve a Java code in Xqery for converting a data string into a yearweek combination in most efficient way.

I am getting below below

```
<ValidFromDttm>2017-02-13T00:00:00.001+00:00</ValidFromDttm>
```

and output should be  --> 201707

Another example --

```
<ValidToDttm>2019-12-08T23:59:59.001+00:00</ValidToDttm>
```

output should be  -->201949

Could someone suggest me if there is any such option available in Xquery

Answer (score 3):

`format-dateTime` has a `[W]` specifier for the week so if you have access to a version respectively processor of XQuery supporting that you can use e.g. `format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(.), '[Y0001][W01]')`, a more complete example is

```
root/date/format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(.), '[Y0001][W01]')
```

which for the input document

```
<root>
    <date>2017-02-13T00:00:00.001+00:00</date>
    <date>2019-12-08T23:59:59.001+00:00</date>
</root>
```

outputs `201707 201949`

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVd

Comment: Seems like this function is available in XQuery 3.0 where as we are still on version 1.0 and I cant see this function there. could you please suggest something on 1.0 pls

Comment: @kumarb, find out which XQuery processor you use and whether it has some proprietary extensions or at least allows you to call into the platform (e.g. Java, .NET) library it is implemented in.

Answer (score 1):

This old post from Jakob Fix might help you: http://x-query.com/pipermail/talk/2010-November/003298.html

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace exslt = "http://exslt.org/dates-and-times";
(: for those implementations without exslt extensions :)
declare namespace date = "http://noexslt.org/dates-and-times";
declare variable $date-time := "2010-01-02T00:00:00Z";
declare variable $month-lengths := (0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31,
30, 31, 30, 31);

(:
 : returns the week of the year as a number.
 :)
declare function date:week-in-year( $date-time as xs:dateTime ) as xs:integer
{
    let $year := fn:year-from-dateTime( $date-time )
    let $day := fn:day-from-dateTime( $date-time )
    let $month := fn:month-from-dateTime( $date-time )

    let $days := sum( subsequence( $month-lengths, 1, $month ) )
    let $is-leap := ($year mod 4 = 0 and $year mod 100 != 0) or $year
mod 400 = 0
    return date:_week-in-year($year, $days + $day + (if ($is-leap and
$month > 2) then 1 else 0))
};

declare function date:_week-in-year( $year as xs:integer, $month-days
as xs:integer) as xs:integer
{
    let $previous-year := $year - 1
    let $is-leap := ($year mod 4 = 0 and $year mod 100 != 0) or $year
mod 400 = 0
    let $dow := ($previous-year + floor($previous-year div 4) -
        floor($previous-year div 100) + floor($previous-year div 400) +
        $month-days) mod 7
    let $day-of-week := if ($dow > 0) then $dow else 7
    let $start-day := ($month-days - $day-of-week + 7) mod 7
    let $week-number := floor(($month-days - $day-of-week + 7) div 7)
cast as xs:integer
    return
        if ($start-day >= 4) then $week-number + 1
        else if ($week-number = 0) then
            let $leap-day := if ((not($previous-year mod 4) and
$previous-year mod 100) or not($previous-year mod 400)) then 1 else 0
            return date:_week-in-year( $previous-year, 365 + $leap-day )
            else $week-number
};

exslt:week-in-year( $date-time ),
date:week-in-year( $date-time cast as xs:dateTime )
```